# Creating barcode's in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, barcode

I am getting an asp.net site developed and need a program which will generate barcode's.
So far all I have found is http://www.barcodelib.com/purchase/main.html#pricebarcodenetweb
Does anyone know of an open source alternative? or a cheaper alternative.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can anyone recommend an open-source .net component to make barcodes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437612/can-anyone-recommend-an-open-source-net-component-to-make-barcodes)

Answer (score 3):

Take [any](http://www.bizfonts.com/free/) barcode fonts. Create an in-memry bitmap image server-side and write the text with the barcode font in the image. Flush the image to the client or save to disk.

http://www.barcodesinc.com/free-barcode-font/
http://www.bizfonts.com/free/

Answer (score 1):

Barcode Generator is a nice option:

[Generating Barcodes with Barcode Generator](http://www.jensbits.com/2011/06/29/generating-barcodes-with-barcode-generator-and-asp-net-vb/)